Buscar repetidos en funcion Random
estoy teniendo una  pequeña crisis con mi codigo necesito que mi funcion BuscarRepetidos me devuelva un true (en caso de haber repetidos ) o false( en caso de no haberlo) y esta funcion meterla dentro de la funcion Guardar_Ramdons y mediante un while   me permita saber si necesito generar nuevos numeros ramdons o no. Ojala me puedan ayudar ya que es para un TP y estoy trabado con este tema y no encuentro el error o la logica. Es en C++
¡Saludos!
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>

void Guardar_Ramdons(int vec[], int Tam);
void MostrarVector(int vec[],int TAM);
bool BuscarRepetidos(int vec[],int TAMANIO);

int main(){
srand(time(0));

const int TAMANIO = 8;
int Num[TAMANIO] , Cartas;

Guardar_Ramdons(Num,TAMANIO);
MostrarVector(Num,TAMANIO);






return 0;
}



void Guardar_Ramdons(int vec[], int Tam){
bool Repeat = true;


while(Repeat  == true ){
Repeat = false;
        for(int x=0;x<Tam;x++){
        vec[x]= ((rand()%20)+1);
        }
    Repeat = BuscarRepetidos(vec,Tam);
    }


}


void MostrarVector(int vec[],int TAM){
    for(int x=0;x<TAM;x++){
        cout << vec[x] << endl;
    }
}

bool BuscarRepetidos(int vec[],int TAMANIO){
    bool Repetido;
    int Contador = 0;
    for(int x=0;x<TAMANIO ;x++){
        for(int i=0;i<TAMANIO;i++){
            if(vec[x]== vec[i+1]){
            Contador++;
            }
        }

    }if(Contador !=0){
        Repetido= true;
    }else{
        Repetido = false;
    }
return Repetido;
} `

  


Bienvenido. Por favor pon el código como texto, como imagen no se puede copiar.

Está mal usar i + 1 ya que cuando i valga TAMANIO - 1 intentará acceder a la posición TAMANIO que no es válida. Por cierto, hay mejores formas de generar números aleatorios no repetidos. Por ejemplo, es mejor generar un número aleatorio y solo agregarlo si no está en la lista. O poblar la lista con números consecutivos y desordenarla.

Mateo beunas tardes ahi comparto el codigo.

Mateo.  igual acabo de eliminar ese FOR con iteracion de i . Solo deje el FOR con x , pero al momento de tirar los ramdons , me sigue tirando los numeros repetidos, en vez de que una vez que encuentre un repetido me vuelva a repartir los numeros de formar aleatoria hasta que dejen de repetirse.

Como primero poblas el arreglo de números pseudo aleatorios, lo que está pasando es que es muy probable que alguno de esos números esté repetido. Comenta el while y la llave de cierre, ejecuta el programa varias veces y lo verás. Lo más simple es que elijas alguna de las opciones que hay en la pregunta que duplicaste.
